# Flutter: Decoding PNG image returns null value

Tags: image, flutter, dart

The following code when run on [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11FOh.png):

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/image.png');
img.Image image = img.decodeImage(byteData.buffer.asInt8List());
print(image.getPixelSafe(0, 0));
```

returns

> NoSuchMethodError: The method 'getPixelSafe' was called on null.

The same code when run on the same image [saved as a JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v7pO.jpg) by replacing the first line with

```
final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/image.jpg');
```

returns

> ImageException: Start Of Image marker not found.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Using the PngDecoder class and decoding the Uint8List instead of Int8List has fixed the issue.

```
img.Image image = img.PngDecoder().decodeImage(byteData.buffer.asUint8List());
```